# How can I prevent updating cell in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, audio

I have a UITableView that is playing an audio clip from the Internet. The audio clip is being played with a singleton helper. When the user taps a button in the cell the audio clip begins and a progress indicator show how much of the audio clip has been played, which works. With this singleton I pass in an update progress block, which updates the cell as it is played.

However, when I scroll through the list of clips, the progress indicator continues to progress for other UITableViewCells. My guess is when I am calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it is returning the cell that is currently being updated by the audio playing singleton. How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT**: The main problem here is that I'm passing in a progress block after playing the sound in `playButtonPressed`. I have the progress update every 0.5 seconds. In other words, if I set the progress to 0 in cellForRow or something like that, it will set back to the current progress after 0.5 seconds.

```
[[Singleton sharedInstance] playURL:url completionHandler:^{
    cell.playButton.selected = NO;
} errorHandler:^{
    cell.playButton.selected = NO;
} progressHandler:^(float progress) {
    if (cell.playButton.selected) {
        [cell.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];                
    }
}];
```

Comment: You are right, in awakeFromNib....how or hide the progress.

Comment: Make sure to set progress  value `nil` before every time  you set value of progress in `cellForRowAtindexPath`, this worked for me.

Comment: That does not work. see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, probably the best way to handle this is to override `prepareForReuse` in your cell class. In here, you can hide the progress indicator, remove it altogether, reset it to zero or whatever makes the most sense in your app:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    progressView.progress = 0   // Or otherwise reset the progress view
}
```

`prepareForReuse` is called – as the name implies – just before the cell is taken out of the reuse queue to be used again. You can use it to put your cell back into a state where any setup that might have been done for a particular index path is reset.

Alternatively, depending on your setup it may make more sense to just look at each cell when it is dequeued, and reset the progress indicator based on whether or not it is the cell currently representing the clip being played by your audio helper.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
    if indexPath.row == audioPlayer.indexOfTrackBeingPlayed {
        cell.progressView.progress = audioPlayer.currentProgress
    } else {
        cell.progressView.progress = 0
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The problem with the update block you added to the question, is that you are capturing the particular cell in that block, but the cell then gets reused elsewhere in the table. Instead, you need to get the cell *from inside* the block using the `indexPath`, so it is always getting the correct cell. For example:

```
[[Singleton sharedInstance] playURL:url completionHandler:^{
    MyCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.playButton.selected = NO;
} errorHandler:^{
    MyCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.playButton.selected = NO;
} progressHandler:^(float progress) {
    MyCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.playButton.selected) {
        [cell.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];                
    }
}];
```

It's slightly cumbersome to have to do this inside each block, but necessary. You could make it slightly neater by defining a convenience property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) MyCell *playingCell;

- (MyCell *)playingCell {
    NSIndexPath *playingIndexPath = // get the index path of the playing item
    return [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:playingIndexPath];
}
```

Then just replace `cell` in your blocks with `self.playingCell`.

Comment: This does not work because I am passing an update block that is running on a timer. See edit.

Comment: Ok, you're capturing the cell instance, so after scrolling it is updating the wrong cell. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because UITableView re-use tableViewCells and one cell can be called for multiple indexPaths depending on availability of cells. There are couple of ways you can fix this issue

1. Don't re-use tableViewCell (not recommanded)
2. Reset progress and Cell UI in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,
3. If you have custom cell create a method which update UI, u can use prepareForReuse method as well, first clear previous UI and then reset it to new UI

Comment: This does not work because I am passing an update block that is running on a timer. See edit.